# How to cause a length_error exception in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make code that throws a length_error exception. My goal is to detect and handle this exception condition. This is my attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string buffer("hi");
    cout<<buffer.max_size()<<endl;
    try {
        while(1) {
            buffer.append(buffer);
        }
    }
    
    catch(length_error &l) {
        cout<<"Caught length_error exception: "<<l.what()<<endl;
    }
    
    catch(exception &e) {
        cout<<"Caught exception: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program I see the max size of the string is 18446744073709551599 bytes. The program continues running until all the memory is used up. Then it just goes quiet. No exception is thrown. The program is still running but its CPU usage went from 100% to around 0%.

Additional information:
OS: Mac OS 10.8.
Compiler: Clang 5.1
RAM: 16 GB

Comment: Is your disk usage pegged? Maybe can't tell unless you have a disk access light. My guess is your machine is thrashing at that point.

Comment: ***No exception is thrown.*** Probably for the reason @FredLarson mentioned. Your system has virtual memory and until you exhaust the limit of how much virtual memory your OS gives to a process it will likely run very slowly (since a disk file is being used as virtual memory) and not throw an exception.

Comment: My disk usage was actually quiet. I opened Activity Monitor and did not see any heavy disk usage going on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your machine is going into virtual memory thrashing due to the memory consumption of growing your string by two characters a LOT of times.

A more effective way of getting this exception is to create a string of size `max_size()+1` at the outset. Here's your code modified to do this, and (for me, at least) it throws the exception you expect instantly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string buffer("hi");
    cout<<buffer.max_size()<<endl;
    try {
        std::string blah(buffer.max_size()+1, 'X');
    }

    catch(length_error &l) {
        cout<<"Caught length_error exception: "<<l.what()<<endl;
    }

    catch(exception &e) {
        cout<<"Caught exception: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am convinced there is something wrong with my computer's implementation of C++. The program crashes because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The exceptions are not even touched. What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: This was using g++ 6.4.0 on Cygwin. Old, but it's what I have handy.

Comment: Thank you very much for you code. I tried your program in Clang 5.1 and Clang 10.0.0.1. It failed to throw an exception both times. When I compiled your program on GCC 10 it worked. I think this is a bug with the Clang compiler. A bug report will be filed soon.

Comment: Did you try @Human-Compiler's suggestion of using `reserve()`?

Answer (score 1):

`std::length_error` is only thrown in a case where a buffer size is known to exceed the container's `max_size()`.

On a modern operating system with virtual memory, it's unlikely to request something that exceeds `max_size()` unless by accident (such as through negative unsigned values), and so the approach you are taking is unlikely to see this exception thrown. Instead, since you're using `append`, you're likely going to just use virtual memory by paging out to disk after you have exhausted your real memory -- which will slow the system down.

If you want to trigger a `length_error`, the easiest way would be to pass something greater than `max_size()` (assuming this is smaller than `std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()`). You should be able to just do something like:

```cpp
auto str = std::string{};
str.reserve(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(-1));
```

or

```cpp
auto str = std::string{};
str.reserve(str.max_size()+1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works with g++ (gcc) but not with clang. I believe this to be a bug with the clang compiler.

Comment: It may not be a bug at all -- it depends entirely on what the implementation chooses `max_size()` to be. Since you are on a system with virtual memory, it's entirely feasible that `max_size()` may return `std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()` (the max size an unsigned value can have -- all bits are set). If this is the case, then `max_size() + 1` will be `0`, which does not exceed the max size.

Comment: Interesting idea. 18446744073709551599 is the reported max size and the log base 2 of 18446744073709551599 is 64. That could be what is happening. Then the next question would be how to limit the max size of a string?

Comment: If you convert that number to binary, you will see that it has an unset bit -- which means that it shouldn't overflow. Using clang on Compiler Explorer, [I was able to trigger the exception](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K4adf3); perhaps there is a bug in the standard library you're using with clang after all?